# App Crash While hitting web Services

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, crash-reports

I have a table view in which Iam selecting a row of the table view and then it hits the web services, retrieves data and then displayed. Now this is my error log Iam getting.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-

```
[__NSCFData setDownloadedLogoImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x806cf90'
*** Call stack at first throw:

(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02abdb99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02c0d40e objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02abf6ab -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02a2f2b6 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02a2ee72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   FlightSearch                       0x000401ef -[AirlineNames connectionDidFinishImage:] + 168
    6   FlightSearch                        0x0002f535 -[SAHttpManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 195
    7   Foundation                          0x001acb96 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFinishLoading] + 108
    8   Foundation                          0x001acaef _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 133
    9   CFNetwork                           0x0307172f _ZN19URLConnectionClient23_clientDidFinishLoadingEPNS_26ClientConnectionEventQueueE + 285
    10  CFNetwork                           0x0313cfcf _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 389
    11  CFNetwork                           0x03066968 _ZN19URLConnectionClient13processEventsEv + 100
    12  CFNetwork                           0x030667e5 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 251
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02a9efaf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x029fd39b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x029fc896 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x029fc350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x029fc271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x032b000c GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x032b00d1 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x00419af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  FlightSearch                        0x00001e86 main + 84
    22  FlightSearch                        0x00001e29 start + 53
    23  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Kindly suggest me what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the message `setDownloadedLogoImage:` to an `NSData` object, which has no idea what to do with it! One of two things has happened:

1) You have not retained something. Take a look at whatever object you expect to call `setDownloadedLogoImage` on and find out where you create it - you should probably be retaining it there ;)

2) (less likely) Your code is just wrong! Add it to your question and we can take a look.